# how to make the <a> link </a> tag work with a submit button?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

how to make the **`<a> link </a>`** tag work with a submit button?
right now send data with a form, but I also need the `<a> link </a>` link to work

My code only works the submit button

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('enviado') }}">
                                 @csrf
                                 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$hoy->id}}">
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send" target="_blank"> <button type="submit">Send</button></a>
     </form>
```

help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try removing the `<a>` tag and just use this on your `<form>` tag

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('enviado') }}" onsubmit="window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send', '_blank');">
```